# PHP show data based on msg_id

Tags: php, mysql

**t_message**
msg_id
message
username
date_post
url

**t_comment**
com_id
comment
msg_id
username
date_comment
url

How can I show comment based on msg_id ?
Example :

john posted message : welcome to my world.
Then jane commented his message : welcome too.
and greg commented too : welcome boss...

other jane posted message : i'm happy today.
then Greg commented her message : wow...

Should be each will be different show right ?

Any suggestions ?

Comment: First of all, you should get data from message table and iterate it by using foreach. For each message record, you can get comments by uısing current msg_id, you can get comments related to that message. You will iterate comments in each message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve comment based on msg_id

```
SELECT c.comment,c.username from t_comment c 
left join t_message m on c.msg_id=m.msg_id 
where c.msg_id={your msg id} 
order by c.date_comment
```

To retrive comments and message based on a msg_id

```
select * from
(select m.message,m.username,m.date_post as date_p,m.msg_id from t_message m
union
SELECT c.comment,c.username,c.date_comment as date_p,c.msg_id from t_comment c 
left join t_message m on c.msg_id=m.msg_id )t
where t.msg_id={your msg id} 
order by t.date_p
```

Comment: sel It should be c.username .

Comment: I guess it should be t_message t left join t_comment c,since a message may not have comment

Comment: Since the question is to show comment based on msgid, i assume just retrieve the comment table. If wanna retrieve message as well, have to use UNION to retrieve message from message table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use such way,

```
//Do your connect operations here

$sql_message = "SELECT * FROM t_message;

$result = mysql_query($sql_message);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "\nMessage : " . $row["message"] . "\n";
    echo "-----Comments : \n"; 

    $sql_comment = "SELECT * FROM t_comments where msg_id = " . $row["msg_id"];
    $result_comments = mysql_query($sql_comment);
    while ($row_comments = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_comments)) {
        echo $row_comments["comment"] . "\n";

    }       
}
```